# Returning specific fields with mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to accomplish something really easy but still manage to fail.

What I am trying to do is when I get a `get` request on my server I want to return all documents BUT just the specific fields populated.

My schema goes as follows

```
var clientSchema = new Schema({
    name:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    phone:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    address: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    }
});

var orderDetailsSchema = new Schema({
    //isn't added to frontend
   confirmed:{
       type: Boolean,
       required: true,
       default: false
   },    
   service:{
       type: String,
       required: true
   },
   delivery:{
       type: String,
       required: false
   },
    payment:{
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    status:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
        default: "new order"
    },
});

var orderSchema = new Schema({

   reference:{
       type: String,
       required: true
   },

    orderdetails: orderDetailsSchema,

    client: clientSchema,

    wheelspec: [wheelSchema],

    invoice:{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Invoice'
    }


});
```

What I want is to return only `client.phone` and `client.email` plus `orderdetails.status` but still retain `reference` field if possible

I have tried using `lean()` and `populate()` but had no luck with them. Is there anything utterly simple I am missing? Or what I am trying to achieve is not that easy? 
Thanks!

Comment: what your get call looks like? you can use mongodb projection

Comment: need to see your current query

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can specify the fields to return like this:

```
Order.findOne({'_id' : id})
        .select('client.phone client.email orderdetails.status reference')
        .exec(function(err, order) {
        //
});
```

Alternative syntax

```
Order.findOne({'_id' : id})
    .select('client.phone client.email orderdetails.status reference')
    .exec(function(err, order) {
      //
});
```

I've made a number of assumptions here, but you should be able to see the idea.

Comment: Works just as I wanted to. Thanks!

Comment: I'm starting with node and I am using Nest with typescript, Is it necessary (best practice) map result to dto when I do a query with filter and return some specific fields (like java) ?

Answer (score 4):

Simply do like this :-

Order is model name which is registered in mongoose.

```
Order.findById(id) // set id you have to get 
   . populate('client')
    .select('client.phone client.email orderdetails.status reference')
    .exec(function(err, order) {
      //
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use projection.

```
await Order.findById(diaryId, {phone: 1, email: 1, status: 1})
```

If phone:1 is set to 1, it is included, if phone:0, then it's excluded.