# Mongoose: how to return only specific field?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

[Returning specific fields with mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44161946/returning-specific-fields-with-mongoose)

I am trying to return the specific field. Applied previously answered solutions on other questions. However, it all returns the entire document and I can't quite work it out.

The data is structured to

```
{
    game: {
        GTA: ['aa'],
        LOL: ['BBBB', 'AAA', 'GGGGG'],
        DOTA: [],
    }
}
```

I am just trying to return `GTA` field.

```
const _type = 'game.GTA'

const result = await db.game
        .collection("game")
        .findOne({ game_id }, [_type]);
```

However, it returns all the document. Moreover, I'd tried

- `findOne({ game_id}, 'game.GTA')`
- `find({....}).select('game.GTA').exec()`

and most solutions I could find on the site. And, yet either it returns `not a function` error or the entire document. How can I just return specific document using `findOne` and variable `_type`?

Comment: try `.findOne({ game_id }, { "GTA": "$game.GTA" });`

Comment: still returning the entire document! :/

Comment: see working [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ruYvLOkV-qy), probably you are missing something else.

Comment: Everything is correct order. Still it returns the entire document . I am just going to do aggregate instead. I will keep trying and when I resolve this, I will wirte you back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use .select() to retrieve specific fields

```
const result = await db.game.collection("game").findOne({ game_id }).select('_type _id name').exec();
```